# How to get an image to anchor to the bottom of a div on a responsive site?

Tags: image, responsive-design

I'm building a new responsive site and I've come across a challenge around a couple of images.

I've got a four column grid using a responsive framework. The section in question (Staff Profiles) can be seen [here](http://customstudio.co/compass).

I've set the images to use roughly half the width of the column, then the text about that person to use the other half. **What I'm trying to do is to get the image to sit on the bottom of the section, even when height of the text area increases due to the screen width being reduced.**

I'm reluctant to use CSS and `position:absolute, bottom:0` as, unless I'm mistaken, this then won't be responsive as the images currently are by using `img {max-width: 100%;}` method.

Any ideas or suggestions are welcome,

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

You can use a media query to set the width's of your div's to 100% at the desired breakpoint. If you want the images to move to the bottom, all you should need to do is switch the position of your div's.

```
<div class="col span_2_of_4">                       
  <div class="half_width right">
    <h2>David Mills</h2>
    <h6>Partner</h6>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
    <a href="#">Find out more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="half_width left thumbnail">
    <img alt="David Mills" src="images/key-people-dave.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col span_2_of_4 second">                        
  <div class="half_width right">
    <h2>Simon Ellis</h2>
    <h6>Partner</h6>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
    <a href="#">Find out more</a>
  </div>
  <div class="half_width left thumbnail">
    <img alt="Simon Ellis" src="images/key-people-simon.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

It looks like your mobile nav populates at 875px, so you could define a media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 875px) {
  .span_2_of_4 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .key_people .half_width.right {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .key_people .half_width.left {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Your images will display below the content, centered and at 100%.